# Custom succes handler never called

Tags: spring, spring-security, spring-security-oauth2

I'm trying to implement an authentication success handler in spring security but it is  never called (authenticationSuccessHandler).

This is my HttpSecurity configuration

```
@Configuration
public class OAuth2ServerConfiguration {

@Configuration
@EnableResourceServer
protected static class ResourceServerConfiguration extends ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter {

    @Inject
    private Http401UnauthorizedEntryPoint authenticationEntryPoint;

    @Inject
    private AjaxLogoutSuccessHandler ajaxLogoutSuccessHandler;

    @Inject
    private MyLoginSuccessHandler authenticationSuccessHandler;

    @Override
    public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
            .exceptionHandling()
            .authenticationEntryPoint(authenticationEntryPoint)
            .and()
            .formLogin()
            .successHandler(authenticationSuccessHandler)
            .and()
            .logout()
            .logoutUrl("/api/logout")
            .logoutSuccessHandler(ajaxLogoutSuccessHandler)
            .and()
            .csrf()
            .disable()
            .headers()
            .frameOptions().disable()
            .and()
            .sessionManagement()
            .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
            .and()
            .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers(HttpMethod.OPTIONS, "/**").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/api/authenticate").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/api/register").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/health/**").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/api/logs/**").hasAnyAuthority(AuthoritiesConstants.ADMIN)
            .antMatchers("/api/**").authenticated()
            .antMatchers("/metrics/**").hasAuthority(AuthoritiesConstants.ADMIN)
            .antMatchers("/trace/**").hasAuthority(AuthoritiesConstants.ADMIN)
            .antMatchers("/dump/**").hasAuthority(AuthoritiesConstants.ADMIN)
            .antMatchers("/shutdown/**").hasAuthority(AuthoritiesConstants.ADMIN)
            .antMatchers("/beans/**").hasAuthority(AuthoritiesConstants.ADMIN)
            .antMatchers("/configprops/**").hasAuthority(AuthoritiesConstants.ADMIN)
            .antMatchers("/info/**").hasAuthority(AuthoritiesConstants.ADMIN)
            .antMatchers("/autoconfig/**").hasAuthority(AuthoritiesConstants.ADMIN)
            .antMatchers("/env/**").hasAuthority(AuthoritiesConstants.ADMIN)
            .antMatchers("/trace/**").hasAuthority(AuthoritiesConstants.ADMIN)
            .antMatchers("/liquibase/**").hasAuthority(AuthoritiesConstants.ADMIN)
            .antMatchers("/api-docs/**").hasAuthority(AuthoritiesConstants.ADMIN)
            .antMatchers("/protected/**").authenticated();

    }
}

@Configuration
@EnableAuthorizationServer
protected static class AuthorizationServerConfiguration extends AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter {

    @Inject
    private DataSource dataSource;

    @Inject
    private JHipsterProperties jHipsterProperties;

    @Bean
    public TokenStore tokenStore() {
        return new JdbcTokenStore(dataSource);
    }

    @Inject
    @Qualifier("authenticationManagerBean")
    private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

    @Override
    public void configure(AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer endpoints)
        throws Exception {

        endpoints
            .tokenStore(tokenStore())
            .authenticationManager(authenticationManager);
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(AuthorizationServerSecurityConfigurer oauthServer) throws Exception {
        oauthServer.allowFormAuthenticationForClients();
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer clients) throws Exception {
        clients
            .inMemory()
            .withClient(jHipsterProperties.getSecurity().getAuthentication().getOauth().getClientid())
            .scopes("read", "write")
            .authorities(AuthoritiesConstants.ADMIN, AuthoritiesConstants.USER)
            .authorizedGrantTypes("password", "refresh_token", "authorization_code", "implicit")
            .secret(jHipsterProperties.getSecurity().getAuthentication().getOauth().getSecret())
            .accessTokenValiditySeconds(jHipsterProperties.getSecurity().getAuthentication().getOauth().getTokenValidityInSeconds());
    }
}
```

and this is my custom implementation

```
@Component
public class MyLoginSuccessHandler implements AuthenticationSuccessHandler {
private static final Logger LOG = 
LoggerFactory.getLogger(MyLoginSuccessHandler.class);
public static final String BEARER_AUTHENTICATION = "Bearer ";

@Inject
private TokenStore tokenStore;

@Override
public void onAuthenticationSuccess(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response,
                            Authentication authentication)
    throws IOException, ServletException {

    LOG.info("YEAH BABY !!");
}
}
```

The onAuthenticationSuccess of my MyLoginSuccessHandler class is never called.

Has someone any idea why ?
Thanks for your help.

Comment: What is the result of your login request? Any HTTP status, any logs or any error message? Why do you think, that your custom handler is not called?

Comment: When I login I don't have the log that I've written in teh custom implementation "LOG.info("YEAH BABY !!");"

Comment: And what do you get?